# Error in the systemcalls C11 for do file i/o

Tags: c, linux, file-io, system-calls, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Hi I'm on Linux WSL Debian and I've the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int fd = open("file.dat", O_RDONLY | O_WRONLY);
    write(fd, "ciao", strlen("ciao"));
    close(fd);
}
```

Why don't works?

Comment: The error is this:
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:10:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘write’; did you mean ‘fwrite’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     write(fd,"ciao",strlen("ciao"));
     ^~~~~
     fwrite
main.c:11:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘close’; did you mean ‘pclose’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     close(fd);
     ^~~~~

Comment: If you need to add more details, put them in the question, not a comment.

Comment: @Cfanlover Following up on Barmar's comment: Did you know you can edit your question? The tiny gray word 'Edit' under the tags is a button.  Yes, it's bad UI design, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You need the header `<unistd.h>` to get the declarations of `write()` and `close()`. The only other header you need is `<fcntl.h>` for `open()`.

I've also kept `<stdio.h>` so I can use `perror()` if `open()` fails.

Since you're only writing to the file, you don't need `O_RDONLY` in the open modes. If you want to read and write, you should use `O_RDWR` instead. These three flags are mutually exclusive.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int fd=open("file.dat",O_WRONLY);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("open failed");
        return 1;
    }
    write(fd,"ciao",strlen("ciao"));
    close(fd);
}
```

Note that this will not create the file if it doesn't already exist. If you want that, you need to add the `O_CREAT` flag and another argument with the permissions that should be given to the file if it's created.

Comment: You might expand a bit as opening with `O_WRONLY` will fail if the file does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Many bugs:

- Must include `unistd.h` for the declaration of `write`.
- `O_RDONLY` and `O_WRONLY` (and `O_RDWR`) are mutually exclusive.  If you want to open a file for read *and* write you have to use `O_RDWR`.  Since you are not actually reading from the file, you should use `O_WRONLY` alone.
- It is very rare to want to use `O_WRONLY` without `O_CREAT` and one (exactly one; these three are also mutually exclusive) of `O_APPEND`, `O_EXCL`, and `O_TRUNC`.  Assuming that you do want `O_CREAT`, you must also supply a third argument, which should be the octal constant 0666 unless you have a specific reason to use some other value.
- `write(fd, "ciao", strlen("ciao"))` should be `write(fd, "ciao\n", strlen("ciao\n"))` unless you have a specific reason to be creating a text file with an incomplete last line.
- Because you are writing to a file, you need to check for errors on *all three of* the `open`, `write`, and `close` calls.  (The fact that `close` can fail is a bug in its specification, but one that we are permanently stuck with.  It's safe to ignore errors in `close` for files that were opened for *reading*, but not writing.)

Also some style corrections:

- The code as shown *only* needs `unistd.h`, `fcntl.h`, and `string.h`; it *should* also be including `stdio.h`, because it *should* also be making calls to `perror`.  None of the other headers should be included (unless this is cut down from a much larger program).
- Declare `main` as `int main(void)` unless you are actually going to use `argc` and `argv`.
- Don't use the C99 license to fall off the end of `main`; the last line of `main` should be `return 0;`.
- For historical reasons, in C, the opening curly brace of a function definition should always be placed on a line by itself, *even if* all other opening curly braces are "cuddled" with their parent control flow construct.